# Forma de buscar %value% en array bidimensional optima

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array bidimensional de muchos valores, y estoy implementando una busqueda para solo **filtrar las filas** que tengan valores similares (%value%),

Encontré este post [How to search an array in Jquery like SQL LIKE %value% statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324798/how-to-search-an-array-in-jquery-like-sql-like-value-statement/5324925) que se ajusta a lo que estoy buscando,

Sin embargo, no estoy seguro si el metodo 2 ("Using indexOf") seria el mas conveniente para mi caso (Array 2D)

1. ¿Debería utilizar `map` o `forEach` o `every` para crear el nuevo array filtrado?

   ```
    let a = [["fo","fool","col","god"],
    ["fo","fol","col","god"],
    ["foo","fol","col","god"],
    ["fo","fol","col","god"]];
    let term = 'oo';
    let b = a.map(value => {
       value .filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1);
    }
    console.log(b)
   ```

**SALIDA REQUERIDA:**

```
[["fo","fool","col","god"],
["foo","fol","col","god"]];
```

2. ¿Utilizar `Using regular expressions` en este caso me seria más útil (tiempo)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yo usaría `filter` como primer operación, ya que el filtrado debe producirse con respecto al array mayor.
- Luego, usaría la función `some` para checkear si al menos un elemento del array menor (`value`) contiene a `term` en su interior usando `indexOf` para ello.
- **En caso** de que también quieras filtrar con respecto a dígitos, puedes convertir cada item en una string usando `String()` .

```js
let a = [["fo","fool","col","god"],
         ["fo","fol","col","god"],
         ["foo","fol","col","god"],
         ["fo","fol","col","god"]];

const term = 'oo';

const b = a.filter(value =>
  value.some(e => String(e).toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >= 0)
);

 console.log(b)
```

Usar expresiones regulares me parece demasiado complejo para el problema, creo que `indexOf` queda más simple.

Comment: Tengo un problema con los number, .toLowerCase es solo para string y me dice "Uncaught TypeError: e.toLowerCase is not a function", deberia verificar con typeof si es string y si es numero pasarlo como false? pasa que si quiero buscar numeros, el term deberia ser dinamico verdad?

Comment: Si queres omitir que revise los numeros podes revisar con type si es una string. Si queres que verifique numeros podes poner "String(e).toLowerCase...." para que te lo transforme

Comment: Genial, si eso era... porque a veces en el input ingresan números o códigos. Quieres modificar la respuesta para que la tilde de respondida?

Comment: @MTDesigner listo!

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que tu pregunta está orientada a encontrar el método que obtenga el resultado con el menor número de iteraciones.

En este caso quieres dejar de buscar una vez que encuentras el primer elemento que cumple con la condición y para eso `String.indexOf()` te funciona bien.

```
let a = [
  ["fo","fool","col","god"],
  ["fo","fol","col","god"],
  ["foo","fol","col","god"],
  ["fo","fol","col","god"]
];
let term = 'oo';
let b = a.filter(list => list.find(word => word.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >=0))
console.log(b)
```

La ruta corta es empezar por filtrar directamente las listas de palabras y haces que el criterio de filtrado sea encontrar la primera palabra en cada lista que contenga el término que buscas (`find` solamente busca el primer elemento que cumpla la condición de búsqueda).

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.